# PrintWriter program

Tags: java, printwriter

Im trying to write a program that will ask for the name of an input file and an output file.  It will open the input file and create the output file.  It will then read the input file and make a double-spaced copy of the input in the output file.

```
public class ProgramTest
    public static void main (String[] args )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("where to read?");
    String in = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("where to write?");
    String out = keyboard.nextLine();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(in));
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(out);
}
```

Thats what I have so far. What I dont know is how to make it do the last part to read the input file and make a double-spaced copy of the input in the output file.

Comment: i would start by googling how to read a file in java

Answer (score 0):

well you can start by reading in the file?

```
private static void readFile(String inputFile) {
        File file = new File(inputFile);
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);   
                 //for example String s = scan.next(); would store next word
                               //doulbe d = scan.nextDouble(); would grab next double
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Once you read in the file sore the lines/numbers into variables?? Should not be to hard work with the read file i provided. Also remember what should you read in first ints or strings?